# Convert bash script into Windows script

Tags: powershell, batch-file

I have the following Unix shell script. I would like to convert this into a Windows `.bat` file (I know I can use Cygwin instead of adapting it to a Windows environment. But Cygwin is not an option for me).

I know I can use Windows PowerShell reading material online. But I don't want to spend hours online learning from basics for this one time requirement. Please don't bash me for being lazy. I am sure this helps others as well by being a quick guide for someone searching online in the future.

Here is the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
echo ""
cat $1 | grep -A4 "Device_name"; echo ""
cat $1 | grep -A45 "Device_Oops"; echo ""
cat $1 | grep -A150 "Processes:" | sed '/Radar/q'; echo ""
cat $1 | grep -E '[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]:[0-9][0-9]' | grep -i -E 'error|restart'
```

To answer questions on what I tried, I have trouble running the "`find`" command which is the equivalent of `grep` per this website http://tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/dosbatch.html

Here is my `Joy.txt` file (next two lines):

```
Device_name router@home
testing only
```

Then at the PowerShell prompt I ran the following command:

```
cat Joy.txt | find "Device_name"
```

I was expecting to see the first line in the above file. But instead I get the parameter format not correct error. Can someone help please?

Comment: Have you tried anything? With what results?

Comment: Windows batch files and Powershell are not the same. Batch files have existed for 20+ years, I think and learning it enough to do the above will take probably an hour or two

Comment: You shouldn't post here because you want to educate others. Show us what you have done so far and we will help you.

Answer (score 5):

A more or less direct equivalent of `grep -A` does not exist in `findstr` (or `find`), Windows' native `grep` equivalent. However, `Select-String` in PowerShell has this with the `-Context` parameter.

If I understand your script correctly, it means:

- Write an empty line
- Write all lines containing "Device_name", followed by four lines of context, followed by an empty line
- Write all lines containing "Device_Oops", followed by 45 lines of context, followed by an empty line
- Write all lines containing "Radar" if they either contain "Processes:" too or are within the first 150 lines following a line containing "Processes:"
- Write all lines containing three pairs of digits, separated by a colon that also contain either "error" or "restart", case-insensitively.

So it more or less comes down to something like:

```
$f = Get-Content $args[0]
function Emulate-Grep {
    begin { $first = $true }
    process {
      if (!$first) { '--' }
      $_.Line
      $_.Context.PostContext
      $first = false
    }
}

Write-Host
$f | Select-String -CaseSensitive -Context 0,4 'Device_name' | Emulate-Grep; Write-Host
$f | Select-String -CaseSensitive -Context 0,45 'Device_Oops' | Emulate-Grep; Write-Host
[string[]]($f | Select-String -CaseSensitive -Context 0,150 'Processes:' | Emulate-Grep) -split "`n" -cmatch 'Radar'; Write-Host
$f -match '\d{2}(:\d{2}){2}' -match 'error|restart'
```

(Untested)

Note that this is slightly ugly due to the attempt to emulate `grep`'s output behaviour.

If you just need matching lines and the following, then I'd simply write a small function:

```
function Get-Matching([array]$InputObject, [string]$Pattern, [int]$Context = 0) {
    $n = $InputObject.Length - 1
    0..$n |
      where { $InputObject[$_] -cmatch $Pattern } |   
      foreach { $InputObject[$_..($_+$Context)] }
}
```

And then use it in a script that isn't so complex anymore (still trying to recreate some of your output choices, e.g. empty lines):

```
$f = gc $args[0]
Write-Host
Get-Matching $f Device_name 4; Write-Host
Get-Matching $f Device_Oops 45; Write-Host
Get-Matching $f 'Processes:' 150 | ? { $_ -cmatch 'Radar' }; Write-Host
Get-Matching $f '\d{2}(:\d{2}){2}' | ? { $_ -match 'error|restart' }
```

You'll also notice that I got rid of `Select-String`, a cmdlet I never really understood the purpose of (except providing a close match of `grep`/`findstr`, but usually I find other means more flexible).

Comment: Appreciate your input. But that's such a complicated script to achieve such simple task of printing a matching line. Can a Windows script be simple like the above bash script? All I need to do is print a matching line (and its following lines) from an input file. Thank you in advance.

Comment: Of course it can. I just more or less assumed that you wanted identical behaviour. I updated the answer.

Answer (score 1):

Regarding Joy.txt, this is an easy one:

```
cat .\Joy.txt | Select-String "Device_Name"
```

[image]