# Century10. Underthewire.tech walkthrough

Tags: powershell, scripting

The password for Century10 is the 161st word within the file on the desktop.

NOTE:
- The password will be lowercase no matter how it appears on the screen.

***The question above is where i am facing my challenges. I tried the command below. ***

```
Get-Content C:\Users\Century9\Desktop\Word_File.txt | Select-Object -Index 161
```

Result was nil. I understand that i need to assign a value to the string as it is now seen as one whole entity. But how do i do it ?

Answer (score 1):

If the token of interest is the **161st *word* in the file**, use the following approach, which **splits the file into words irrespective of line breaks**<sup>[1]</sup>:

```
$pass = (-split (Get-Content -Raw Word_File.txt))[160]
```

<sup>Append `.ToLower()` if you want to convert the token to all-lowercase.</sup>

Note that the above loads the entire file into memory as a single string, using `-Raw`.

- Since array indices are `0`-based, it is index `[160]` that returns the 161st element.
- The unary form of the [`-split` operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_split) splits the input into an array of tokens *by whitespace*.

  - Note: If you want to split by the stricter definition of what constitutes a word in a regular-expression context, use the following instead:

```
$pass = ((Get-Content -Raw Word_File.txt) -split '\W+' -ne '')[160]
```

---

<sup>[1]</sup> **If your input file contains each word *on its own line***:

Your solution was on the right track, except that you should pass `160` to `Select-Object -Index`, because the `-Index` parameter expects *`0`-based indices*, not `1`-based *line numbers*:

```
# Extract the 161st line.
$pass = Get-Content Word_File.txt | Select-Object -Index 160
```

To convert to lowercase:

```
$pass = (Get-Content Word_File.txt | Select-Object -Index 160).ToLower()
```

The above will *fail* if the input file has *fewer* than 161 lines (with error message `You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression`).

If you prefer to receive *no output* quietly instead, use the following (which uses built-in aliases `select` for `Select-Object` and `foreach` for `ForEach-Object` for brevity):

```
$pass = Get-Content Word_File.txt | select -Index 160 | foreach ToLower
```

Comment: any idea on where i should start to master powershell and learn scripting ? I tried my research and underthewire website appears to be one of the website which turn up upon searching. Thank you nevertheless for your answers :)

Comment: @JellyRainbows: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48491292/45375 contains some pointers to resources for getting started. Also, allow me to give you the standard advice to newcomers in the next comment.

Answer (score 0):

Try running this:

```
((Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Century9\Desktop\Word_File.txt -TotalCount 161)[-1]).ToLower()
```

Comment: Method invocation failed because [System.Char] does not contain a method named
'ToLower'.
At line:1 char:1
+ ((Get-Content -Path C:\Users\Century9\Desktop\Word_File.txt -TotalCou ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (:) [], RuntimeException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : MethodNotFound

Comment: @JellyRainbows: That would only happen if you used `1` with `-TotalCount`; to avoid that problem, use `@(...)` rather than `(...)` around the `Get-Content` command.