# Why does adding to an ArrayList count whats being passed to it?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

Hello and good evening to yall

I was looking to see if I can get some assistance in suppressing the count when adding to ArrayList. For some reason I dont understand even after my google searches, I just can't suppress the count.

```
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$AStuff = @()
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$CStuff = @()
[System.Collections.ArrayList]$Rest = @()

switch -Wildcard (gci C:\users\abrah\OneDrive\Desktop){
    "D*" {$AStuff.Add($_)}
    "C*" {$CStuff.Add($_)}
    Default {$Rest.Add($_)}
    }

for($i=0; $i -lt ($AStuff.Count + $CStuff.Count + $Rest.Count); $i++){
    [pscustomobject]@{
        "Letter A" = $AStuff[$i]
        "Letter C" = $CStuff[$i]
        "Rest " = $Rest[$i]
    }
}
```

the output is:

```
0
1
0
1
0
1
2
3
2
3
4

Letter A Letter C                  Rest                            
-------- --------                  -----                           
dir1     CFR-2008-title38-vol1.pdf Test                            
dir2     cs.csv                    v1                              
         CSV                       error.png                       
         csvv.csv                  Screenshot 2021-01-09 195943.png
                                   v2.pdf
```

Can someone educate me on what is going on in regards to why it outputs the count?

Please dont feel the need to answer if its something really simple, a brief explanation will do and I should be able to fix it if thats the case.

- On a side note, is there a more efficient way to add to an object like its shown above?

Comment: Please pardon my ignorance if im not explaining it correctly

Comment: In short: any output - be it from a command or a .NET method call - that is neither captured nor redirected (sent through the pipeline or to a file) is _implicitly output_. To simply _discard_ such output, it's best to use `$null = ...`; see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/55665963/45375) to the linked duplicate. Here, the [`.Add()` method](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.ArrayList.Add) produces implicit output (the index of the newly added element).

Comment: @Mkelement0, thank you for that; gave it an extra upvote. Where do you recommend I learn more about this type of stuff? Any books? Websites? (Ive read up on both "Learn Ps in a month of lunches", and "PS for SysAdmins") I just feel like theres a lot more I can learn. Should I dive into .net and C# for a better understanding of PS?

Comment: Thanks, Abraham. A while back I compiled a short list of learning resources in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48491292/45375). It certainly helps to know about .NET data types and APIs, but I wouldn't start there; I'd say C# is only needed for understanding code samples in the .NET documentation. Otherwise: PowerShell is great for hands-on experimentation, and you'll also find plenty of good information in the answers her on SO.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just because `Add` method returns an int :

```
$a =@()
$a.Add

OverloadDefinitions                 
-------------------                 
int IList.Add(System.Object value)
```

So in you case you can avoid it using `| out-null`.

```
$AStuff.Add($_) | out-null
```